# Microsoft Access 2003 =SUM() function multiplying by constant

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am using Microsoft Access 2003 alongside visual basic. I am currently trying to have it so that I can add the weights of a group of select products. For the most part, it works successfully. I calculate the weight based off the quantity and the product itself. Individually, every weight appears to be correct. The expression I use for an individual product (field titled as WeightSum) is:

```
=DLookUp("[Weight]","[Products]","[ProductID] =  " & [Forms]![Orders]![Orders Subform].`[Form].[ProductID].[Value])*[Forms]![Orders]![Orders Subform].[Form].[Quantity].[Value]
```

I think that works fine. Now, for my totalWeight, I tried to simply use this:

```
=SUM([WeightSum])
```

This works for AS LONG as another field, "Size" is not a specific value (8x10). I've noticed that for every product with a size of "8x10", it takes the weight in the individual category and multiplies it by 1.5 throughout the SUM calculation. I cannot find any indicator of code telling it to do that, and I don't think the expression I provided would make it do that. Other sizes work fine.

For example, if I have 3 products:

- Product A: Quantity: 200 Size: 5x5, Weight: 0.10 `(Quantity * Weight = 20)`
- Product B: Quantity: 150 Size: 4x4, Weight: 0.12 `(Quantity * Weight = 18)`
- Product C: Quantity: 100 Size: 8x10, Weight: 0.13 `(Quantity * Weight = 13)`

I should get 41 lbs, but I don't. I really get 57.5, since the 13 was multiplied by 1.5 for some odd reason

The only thing I can think of and based off what I have read) is that it has something to do with the fact that the values I'm summing are calculated values, and not stripped from a table. However, I couldn't seem to figure out how to add the values. and I'm not sure why this method would multiply only SOME by a factor of 1.5

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check if the name of the controls match the name of their bound field.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding... I don't completely know which is which. I see WeightSum as the name for individual weights, TotalWeight for the name of the field with the summed up weights. In the total weight field, I have =SUM([WeightSum]), and in the WeightSum field, for control source, I have the first Dlookup I provided in the original post.

Comment: You seem to confuse `Controls` and `Fields`. Controls are the textboxes, combos.. on the form. They have their own name, even if Controls often have the same name as their bound field. They can be unbound, or bound to a field, or bound to an expression. In your case of an unexpected result, check the control names.

Comment: I'm looking at it, and I want to say they're okay. I only really have 2 boxes. http://imgur.com/wEFXzJA,wDtkgdA I made a temporary "test" box (Text49) and I did the same thing. As you can see, the weights are adding up.. just incorrectly (the 2nd and 4th row are the screwed up "8x10" sizes)

Comment: Can you post your entire code that uses these calculations?

Comment: I'm not sure what else to include. I don't think I really have an intermediary step in between the individual weights and the final weight.

Comment: post the entire SQL or entire VBA sub if you have it?

Comment: It's a fairly large project. If I find something that even remotely relates to size, weight, or those fields, I'll post it.

Comment: I'm not concerned with anything outside of what you are asking about. Where did you get the `DLookup` code from? Post that.

Comment: Do you mean the table? http://imgur.com/YqqvbXB

Comment: `Size` is nowhere in your calculation, so I have to conclude something else is happening.  Need more information.